# use key to retrive data out of dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have read a CSV file into a dictionary, where the `code3` is they key. I then use the `def findAirportCODE(self, code3):` to get the key and print out the data associated with the key. The `code3` is entered via an input in `a.findAirportCODE(input('enter a code').upper())`.

```
import csv

class Airport:

    def __init__(self, airportname='', cityname='', countryname='', code3='', lat=0, long=0):

        self.airportname=airportname
        self.cityname=cityname
        self.countryname=countryname
        self.code3=code3
        self.lat=lat
        self.long=long

class TravelLookUp:
    def dictAirport(self,filename):
        self.__airportDict={}

        f=open(filename, encoding="utf8")
        csvreader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in csvreader:
            airport=Airport(row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[6], row[7])
            self.__airportDict[row[4]]=airport
            #for keys, values in self.__airportDict.items():
                #print ('[', keys, ':', values.airportname,']')


    def findAirportCODE(self, code3):
        print( self.__airportDict[code3])

air=Airport()
a=TravelLookUp()
a.dictAirport('airport.csv')
a.findAirportCODE(input('enter a code').upper())
```

When I run this program it shows:

```
 enter a code: jfk
<__main__.Airport object at 0x02B826F0>
 enter a code: dub
<__main__.Airport object at 0x02ABB5F0>
```

The program is reading from the CSV file as when I enter a different `code3` it shows a different code as above.

The CSV file it is reading from is formatted like this:

```
3796,Kapalua,Lahania-kapalua,United States,JHM,PHJH,20.962936,-156.673031,256,-10,N,Pacific/Honolulu
3797,John F Kennedy Intl,New York,United States,JFK,KJFK,40.639751,-73.778925,13,-5,A,America/New_York
3798,Homestead Arb,Homestead,United States,HST,KHST,25.48855,-80.383567,6,-5,A,America/New_York
3799,Riverside Muni,Riverside,United States,RAL,KRAL,33.951875,-117.445103,818,-8,A,America/Los_Angeles
```

Why am I getting this message, and how do I get it to print out the correct information aka the data associated with the dictionary's key?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? If you are using Python 2, then you should be using "new-style" objects and declare your classes like this: `class Airport(object):` and `class TravelLookUp(object):`. Notice the additional `(object)` which declares `object` as the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply override the `Airport` class' special [`__str__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) so that it returns in string form the information that you want.

You are currently printing out the object, and that string that you see is the default way of representing an object in Python. It may look funny, but it tells you the type of object and its unique identifier.

These identifiers are not the same on different runs as you have observed because Python does not guarantee they are the same across different runs.

You asked how to implement `__str__`, so here's an example:

```
    # inside your existing class Airport definition
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s in %s, %s' % (self.airportname, self.cityname, self.countryname)
```

You can get as fancy or as simple as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Your Airport has no `__str__` method so Python doesn't know how to print it out.

Implement `__str__`, or alternately replace your Airport class with a `collections.namedtuple` to get automatic printing and several useful features:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Airport = namedtuple('Airport', 'airportname cityname countryname code3 lat long')
```

Comment: When you say implemet a __str__ method, does that mean write a def  __str__(self):, and if so when am i meant to put in to it? return it?

Comment: Return a suitable string version of your Airport. See the Python docs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a list as your dictionary value rather than an object for this simple example. If you're going to use the values in the list you could always cast them during the import process to make sure you've got the right type. To get around the issue of typing in the list, you could also use json to carry some type information for you.